# Dimension of product variety using finite morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, krull-dimension

I've read the following proof for $\dim(X\times Y)=\dim(X)+\dim(Y)$ with $X,Y$ algebraic varieties. Because dimension is a birrational property we can suppose that $X,Y$ are affine. Now, Noether normalization theorem implies that exists finite surjective maps $f:X\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n,g:Y\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{A}^m$. Then we have a surjective map $f\times g:X\times Y\twoheadrightarrow\mathbb{A}^{n+m}$. As srujective finite morphisms preserves dimension, it is sufficient proof $f\times g$ is a finite morphism, but I don´t know why it is finite. Recall that in the affine case, a morphism $f:X\to Y$ is finite iff the ring of regular functions $\mathscr{O}(X)$ is integral over $\mathscr{O}(Y)$ via the pullback $f^*:\mathscr{O}(Y)\to\mathscr{O}(X)$, ie, if $\mathscr{O}(X)$ is a finitely generated $\mathscr{O}(Y)-$module.

Comment: Hint: can you show that if $f:X\to Y$ is a finite morphism, then $f\times id_Z:X\times Z \to Y\times Z$ is a finite morphism?

Comment: I think that I have the idea. In this case the pullback is $(f\times id_Z)^*:\mathscr{O}(Y\times Z)\to\mathscr{O}(X\times Z)$, and now as $Y\times Z,X\times Z$ are affine, his regular functions rings are $\mathscr{O}(Y\times Z)\cong \mathscr{O}(Y)\otimes\mathscr{O}(Z),\mathscr{O}(X\times Z)\cong \mathscr{O}(X)\otimes\mathscr{O}(Z)$. Under this identificatión, the pullback is $(f\times id_Z)^*=f^*\times id_Z$ and is an algebra exercise proof that tensor with identity preserves integral property. Finally, $f\times g=f\times id_Z\circ id_Z\times g$ and composition of finite morphism is finite.

Comment: I appreciate suggerences and comments.